# What's the wrong with my Spring MVC autowiring code and @SessionAttribute?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to `Serialize` my `@Service` for adding the `@SessionAttribute` to my `@Controller`.

The problem now that there are `@Autowired` `@Repository` inside that `Service` class for loading the repositoy and it doesn't load after `Deserializing` the service object. although of i have used `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` but no thing solved.

```
package jas;

@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication 
@ComponentScan
public class BackofficeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackofficeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
package jas.controllers;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"permissionsForm"})
public class PermissionsController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("permissionValidator")
    private Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    private Permissions permissionsAdd;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinber(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    @ModelAttribute("viewTemplate")
    public String createviewTemplate(){
        return "permissions-add";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("permissionsForm")
    public Permissions permissionsAdd(){
        return permissionsAdd;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/permissions:add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    private String addGet(Model model) {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
package jas.beans.services;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import jas.beans.Role;
import jas.beans.repo.PermissionsRepository;

@Component
public class Permissions implements Serializable{ 
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -495480557873675142L;

    @Autowired
    private static PermissionsRepository repository;

    // Form
    private HashMap form = new HashMap();

    public Permissions(){
    }

    public PermissionsRepository getRepository(){
        if(this.repository == null){
                    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); 
        }

        return this.repository;
    }

    public Iterable<Role> getAll(){
        return this.getRepository().findAll();
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
package jas.beans.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import jas.beans.Role;

@Component
public interface PermissionsRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.username = ?1")
    Role findbyUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to store the @Service in the session?

Comment: @AlanHay Hi , Simply i want to `clear` the web form that the `service` has been assigned to it using `@ModelAttribute` , so as i read , i have to use `SessionAttribute` in adddition to `SesstionStatus' to set it complet for inavlidate the session to set the modelattribute clear , thus the form won't store the data again after submitting it , correct me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain why you need to hold the form in the session, but assuming that you do, and you cannot simply have the values sent in the 'addGet' request, e.g.

```
private final PermissionsRepository permissionsRepository;

@Autowired
public PermissionsController(PermissionsRepository permissionsRepository) {
    this.permissionsRepository = permissionsRepository;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/permissions:add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
private String addGet(@RequestParameter String username, Model model) {
    return permissionsRepository.findByUsername(username);
}
```

So, assuming that's not possible here is another solution:

In order to get Permissions to serialise you need to separate your form from your service (this will also lead to a neater implementation as you separate your data from you business logic).

1. Change Permissions to a PermissionsForm object which is a simple java bean storing the properties for your HTTP request. i.e. not a component, no dependencies
2. Autowire your PermissionsRepository into your controller (as above)
3. In your controller method call permissionsRepository.findbyUsername(permissionsForm.getUsername()) (as above)

By doing this you're allowing your state (form data) to be serialised and your logic (permissions repository) to be a stateless singleton managed by Spring.

As an aside, there is a bug in your implementation, your Permissions component is not thread safe because it's storing Web request state in the private 'form' field. Since this component is a singleton all web requests would try to overwrite the form value leading to unpredictable results.

Comment: Thank you , frankly i'm not trying to save the form fields inside my `Service` Component. vice versa is correct.

Simply `i have a form and i want to clear its fields' values' after submitting the form successfully . `After validation' 

My knowledge might be confused about Spring MVC